# Selecionar item em ListBox com Binding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml, silverlight, binding

Tenho uma lista de contatos:

```
<ListBox Name="lstContatos">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Tap="txtTelefone_Tap" Width="45" VerticalAlignment="Center"
Name="imgFoto"
Source="{Binding Foto}" />
                    <TextBlock Tap="txtTelefone_Tap" Name="txtNome" Height="Auto"
FontSize="28"
VerticalAlignment="Center"
Margin="4,0,0,0"
Text="{Binding Nome}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tel" Tap="txtTelefone_Tap" Height="Auto"
Margin="48,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
FontSize="22" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
FontWeight="Bold"
Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Telefone}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Pego meus contatos e armazeno nela com a classe Contato:

```
public class Contato
{
    public object Foto { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
}
```

Até aqui está 100% funcional, o app exibe meus contatos, porém quero fazer uma ação quando algum contato da lista for selecionado, tentei usando:

```
private void txtTelefone_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Contato s in dados)
    {
        num.Text = numero = s.Telefone;
    }
    myPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

O objetivo é pegar o numero daquele contato que foi pressionado, como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui com o seguinte:

```
private void txtTelefone_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var mySelectedItem = lstContatos.SelectedItem as Contato;
    num.Text = numero = mySelectedItem.Telefone;
    myPivot.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```